# How to find which version of Laravel no longer has security vulnerability

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, dependabot

I have a Laravel project on Github, and the dependabot email is warning me of a security vulnerability in Laravel's symfony/http-foundation dependancy (the vulnerability is in version >= 3.0.0 and < 3.4.26.

Is there a way to determine what is the lowest version of Laravel that is using a version of this dependancy >= 3.4.26.

I don't have time to migrate to the latest versions, so I'm looking to migrate to the lowest version of Laravel that doesn't have this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 and later use `symfony/http-foundation` >= `3.4.26`

It in fact uses `~3.2` which means `3.2 <= version < 4`

Laravel 5.3 uses `3.1.*`

Comment: Thanks! How can I determine this in the future?

Comment: @Sandy I just went to the laravel framework github and went back through composer.json versions. Took 2 minutes. There might be a fancy way, but I don't think so.